# Can I get a larger side task bar in Windows 10, to read more of the label?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I can do right click on the Taskbar, select 'properties' and then select "left" for the "Taskbar location on screen" under "Taskbar".

However the label next to the icon (e.g. the name of an open Word document) is only up to three letters, whereas I get at least 16 characters if the toolbar is displayed at the top/bottom.

The solution would be, to make the sidebar wider, but there seems to be no option for that.

FYI, I am using the sidebar to save vertical screen real estate. It's 2018, all screens are wide, but all software incl. all browsers crams all their info, tabs, bookmarks or ribbons into the precious vertical screen estate. Google Chrome briefly had an experimental feature for side tabs, but then canceled the project.

Comment: You may want to look into Vivaldi, a chrome based browser that does allow tab placements to go on the left or right side.

Comment: Thanks. I checked out Vivaldi. It's very nice. Unfortunately one saves almost no vertical screen estate, because Vivaldi will show blank on the tob bar where Chrome places it's tabs. I couldn't find how to remove that top bar in Vivaldi - or better for remove it for all Windows programs. I hardly ever resize windows and when I do, I use the windows-key + arrow-key shortcut to arrange two windows next to each other. Closing programs on the task bar or with Alt+F4. So this top bar in Windows is a total waste to me.

Comment: Another option in Vivaldi is to zoom out the entire user interface. I have it zoomed to 70% which makes everything a lot smaller. It doesn't matter anymore that it is at the top for me, though it would work as well at the sides. You can also hide the addressbar, but that would basically stop you from being able to type in an address until you show it again. Adding google to your tile page or as new tabs page could substitute for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can!  Right click on the task bar, and make sure that "Lock all taskbars" is unchecked.  After that, you should get a resize cursor when you hover on the border of the task bar and  the desktop.  You can click and drag as you would any other Window.

You can then recheck "Lock all taskbars" in order to not accidentally resize later.